# MySQL join performance with order by for large tables. Missing index?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have the following two tables:

```
requests: id, file_id

request_filter_integers: id, request_filter_id, value
```

and I want to fetch data with the following query:

```
select `requests`.`id`, `sum_followers`.`value` as `sum_followers`
from `requests`
  left join `request_filter_integers` as `sum_followers` on `sum_followers`.`request_id` = `requests`.`id` and `sum_followers`.`request_filter_id` in (63002331)
where `requests`.`file_id` in (3571851, 3574928, 3576373, 10000857, 10001207, 10001258, 10001516, 10001528)
order by `sum_followers`.`value` desc limit 51 offset 0
```

This query takes forever and I am not sure if there is an index/order issue or if it's generally limited by the way the table structure/join is setup. 
requests contains about 150 million rows with 10k different file_ids. request_filter_integers has 130 millionen rows.
The where file_id IN clause in the query limits the requests rows to 1 million.

EXPLAIN for the above query returns:

[image]
and I have the following indexes:

requests table:
[image]

request_filter_integers table:

[image]

Comment: Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for both tables. This will give us a better overview of the indices.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: And provide those `SHOW CREATE TABLEs` as _text, not images_.

Answer (score 0):

You have a request file_id column without index  but used in where clause

so you should use   a  composite index  for table request on columns `(file_id, id )`

and you should also avoid a IN clause for several values  for this you could try using a join. (with a subquery on union or a a proper table for the  IN  values  )

a subquery as

```
select 3571851 file_id 
union 
select 3574928 
union 
select 3576373 
union 
select 10000857 
union 
select 10001207 
union 
select 10001258 
union 
select 10001516 
union 
select 10001528
```

should return the same values and the your query could be modified  this way

```
select `requests`.`id`, `sum_followers`.`value` as `sum_followers`
from `requests`
INNER JOIN ( 
    select 3571851 file_id 
    union 
    select 3574928 
    union 
    select 3576373 
    union 
    select 10000857 
    union 
    select 10001207 
    union 
    select 10001258 
    union 
    select 10001516 
    union 
    select 10001528
    ) t o t.file_id = requests.file_id
left join `request_filter_integers` as `sum_followers` on `sum_followers`.`request_id` = `requests`.`id` 
and `sum_followers`.`request_filter_id` in (63002331)
order by `sum_followers`.`value` desc limit 51 offset 0
```

Comment: there are already two composite indexes with file_id as the first column:
file_id, created_at & file_id, email_sha256. I don't think file_id, id would make any difference (pls correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: ...  in where/  clause  you have  file_id, id  ..so this  si my suggestion  ..  anyway  .. you could just try .